# Can I jump to anchor / tab using OnClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I thought this one was easy but I'm banging my head on the jumping part. I have a page, on this page I have tabs, I want to click on the 'read' link so that it (1) opens the tab and (2) jumps to that part of the page so user can keep reading. My code:

```
<a onclick="$('a[href=#tab-read]').click();">Read</a>
```

Like I said, works just fine, opens the tab I need but doesn't actually make the jump to it? I still have to scroll down the page to get to the content area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, you can force the window to go anchor tag, or change up the selector to go to the desired element :)

```
$(window).scrollTop($('a[href=#tab-read]').offset().top);
```

Comment: Bryan, I'm happy that you are helping me again, thanks for that. It scrolls down to the tab area but now it no longer opens the required tab. In effect I now have my problem in reverse...scrolls down where it needs to but if I have a different tab open, it won't scroll and open proper tab.

Comment: Hey SirDufus, glad to be helping again :) Can you show me the current code you have, so I can build on that to give you a working example?

Comment: `<?php echo $description; ?><a onclick="$(window).scrollTop($('a[href=#tab-read]').offset().top);">Read</a></div>`

Comment: Alright, sorry for the delay. Basically, in your onclick, you'll want to target the appropriate div. Let's say your div has a class "class_name", your onClick will actually want to look something perhaps more like this. 

onclick="$(window).scrollTop($('div.class_name').siblings().hide().end().show().offset().top);"

What this will do, is target the desired div, hide all of it's siblings, end() returns control to the selected div, then show(), then grab the offset().top for the initial call to scrollTop. The command I've given you, will accomplish all of that for you

Comment: Thanks Brian, makes things even worse as it now hides all the page content while only showing the active tab. So yes technically it does what I asked for, but I just wanted to make the tab active to show the content, not hide all the page contents. I don't want to take up too much of your time so I'll award your the answer. Thanks for trying to help...

Comment: You're welcome, just a pointer, make sure that the targetted divs, are nested inside of another div, so that the div's siblings, are limited to the ones inside of the targetted container <div class="parent"><div class="target_div"></div><div class="sibling_div"></div><div class="sibling_div"></div></div> etc.. :)